# Как интерфейсы предотвращают проблему СРСа?

Tags: java, интерфейс

стал более глубоко изучать Java и задался вопросом: Как интерфейсы в Java предотвращают проблему Смертоносного Ромба Смерти? Как так это получается? Ведь по сути, когда класс реализует интерфейс и наследуется от класса, то он тоже создаёт проблему СРСа, разве нет? 
Вот пример Смертоносного Ромба Смерти:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблем с наследованием реализации две. Первая касается полей класса, вторая — реализации.

На вашей диаграмме видно, что поле `i` наследуется классами `CDBurner` и `DVDBurner`. Надо ли в `ComboBurner` делать два поля `i` или это должно быть одно поле? К сожалению, правильного ответа на этот вопрос нет — зависит от предметной области.

То же самое касается реализаций `burn()`, которые могут отличаться в `CDBurner` и `DVDBurner`. Какую из них использовать при наследовании?

Все эти разночтения отпадают в случае интерфейсов, поскольку в них нет полей данных и в них все методы чистые абстрактные, то есть не имеют реализации.

За это есть плата — мы вынуждены дублировать реализацию. Эта проблема имеет решение: надо вынести реализацию в отдельный класс, и вызывать его методы в наследниках наподобие `ComboBurner`. Авторы классической книжки про паттерны, так называемая *Банда Четырёх* (Gang of Four, GoF) писали в этой самой книжке о том, что агрегирование предпочтительней наследования. Этот подход упрощает разработку в таких языках как Java и C#.

Кстати, в C# есть концепция *свойств* (properties), которые могут присутствовать в интерфейсах, в отличие от полей. Это потому, что свойства — синтаксический сахар. По сути это пара методов, геттер и сеттер, которые тоже могут быть чисто абстрактными, то есть не иметь реализации.